# python select sublist effectively

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublist

I have a long (many Millions) list of Transactions in the form [account_id, transactiontyp, data], each account has many Transactions. I want to select all transactions for a given short list (approx. 20000) of accounts. Example:

```
longlist=[['a','t1',5],['a','t1',9],['b','t1',3],['c','t5',8]]

shortlist=['a','c']
```

The following code does the trick, but is extremly slow:

```
selection=[sel for sel in longlist if sel[0] in shortlist]
```

There must be faster ways to accomplish that? I tried

```
def select_sample(longlist,shortlist):
    ret=[]
    for elem in longlist:
        if elem[0] in shortlist:
            ret.append(elem)
    return ret
```

to see how it scales, as expected it is linear in the size of longlist.
Longlist is sorted by account_id. I do not have a unique key in longlist to use dictionaries.
Is there something like an index-technique, which I could use?

Comment: You can use binary search for single accounts [see documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) but then you need to execute that for each account. I think there should exist something better.

Comment: you can try with generators

Comment: Not quite a complete solution, but do consider using a `set` instead of a list to check against: `shortset = set(shortlist)` and `sel[0] in shortset`.

Comment: You could transorm the list of transactions into a dictionary, but I don't know if that is viable for your case (time, space). @omri_saadon generators will only lessen memory consumption but are not faster.

Comment: you can spend some time creating a database from the data you have and then just query it. I have done something very similar using sqlite3 in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `set` (`shortlist = set(['a', 'c']`) would have a break-even at around *20* accounts. I'd expect it to be at least 2 decades faster if `shortlist` has 20k accounts.

If this selection is repeated many times, you'd benefit *even* more by using a dictionary that maps account name to list of transactions for that specific account.

---

However, all in all this smells like an XY problem. Surely you should use a RDBMS to manage this data? They have got efficient algorithms to handle exactly these kinds of queries.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem for now. I would appreciate a hint/link to understand: why does this make such a difference? Is python iterating over shortlist for each Observation?

Comment: Yes. See [Time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), time spent for `x in s` grows linearly for list, and is constant for set as they grow in size.